# Change Database Column Design in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I have a production database which I need to make a change from varchar to nvarchar in the column design. I know I can force it to re-create the design and save it but is it a good idea to do so?

What could be the outcomes and any other suggestions?

Update: Its SQL Server 2008

Comment: How big is the table? Is the database in constant use or is there an out of hours period where updates can be run with no impact on users?

Answer (score 0):

@Ye Myat Aung, You can directly change the data type from varchar to nvarchar. No need to recreate the structure. Just take care of the size of the column, because nvarchar is saving data in unicodes, it will be almost double to the varchar.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to create a test database from the production database and run the script to update the field type.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the following steps:

1. Open the table in design view.
2. Now you change the datatype from varchar to NVarchar at design time and not to save it.
3. Now you press "Change generate Script" which is available on top left side of header  bar.
4. Save the script and execute it.

This is the most save solution for production servers to avoid any data loss.

Answer (score 0):

If you would be using Visual Studio Database edition to generate the deployment script this would be automatically created for you. However, what it does in behind is as follows

1) Create table with the new definition. Just name your table with {TableName}_new.
2) Create the indexes as you have on the old table
3) Create The triggers as you had on the old table (and disable them)
4) Copy over the data from the old table to new table.
5) Rename the Old Table by appending _old to the table name
6) Rename the new table by dropping the _new from the name